# Is there a reliable way to determine the location of App_Data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7.5, connection-string, app-data

I'm using the App_Data directory for SQLite in MVC4/Visual Studio 2010. `System.Data.SQLite` wants the DB path in the connection string.

Is there a way to reliably resolve the location of App_Data for my connection string that won't require code changes or if() statements?

Comment: Not sure what you meant by App_Data. Have you tried Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData?

Comment: Add_Data is a folder in every Visual Studio 2010 C# project. It's meant to be a place for the application to write data to disk safely, so is often used with embedded databases like SQLite and MS SQL Compact Edition. I haven't tried `Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData` but I'll look into it. Thanks!